# I am looking for an algorithm for dividing N numbers into K groups and for each group to have S players

Tags: javascript

I am looking for an algorithm for dividing N numbers into K groups and for each group to have S players.

```
split(array, k, s);

            var array = [5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1]; // sum : 26
            var k = 3;// number of groups;
            var s = 3;// number of players;

            // 26/3 = 8.66 => sum in each group

            // result : 
            //group 1 : { 5, 3, 1 } sum: 9 
            //group 2 : { 5, 3, 1 } sum: 9,
            //group 3 : { 5, 2, 1 } sum: 8,
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple greedy approach is optimal. Just grab next highest from the array and put it in the group that's the smallest.

```js
const array = [5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1];
let groups = [[], [], []];
array.forEach(val => {
  const counts = groups.map(group => group.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0)); 
  groups[counts.indexOf(Math.min(...counts))].push(val);
});
console.log(groups);
```

EDIT:

Oof, didn't read well enough. Simplest approach might be to even player count after: Just keep move the smallest value from the largest group (by size) to the smallest until groups are equal size.

You'll have to convince yourself if that's optimal, I'm not sure offhand.